# Statement of Purpose and Personal Statement examples

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

I am applying to some schools in the UC system for graduate school, and I have to write a Statement of Purpose and a Personal Statement. I was wondering if there are some good examples online, so I can have a better idea of what is expected.

Comment: After a second read, I see that it is not a duplicate. I think I misinterpreted the question. Please excuse me.

Comment: @padawan No worries!

Comment: A personal statement is personal - why would someone post theirs online so you can copy it? Write your personal statement - it is about you...